# nonmonotone SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to writing SQL queries and am getting stuck on some simple ones, I need to find `drinkers who only like bud`

for first one:

```
SELECT drinker
FROM likes
WHERE beer = 'Bud';
```

**Likes(drinker,beer)**

I am aware that the above query will return every drinker that likes bud, I am having trouble transitioning into every drinker that **only** likes bud.

Comment: You should not ask 2 distinct questions in one post. It may happen that an answer is really good in the 1st question, but not that good on the 2nd one, and another question does it vica versa.

Comment: @Shadow edited post

Comment: You just need to be sure of `HAVING` only 1 likes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this question. I prefer to use the one with [not exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) subqueries because the subquery in this case does not pull the actual data therefore it is fast:

```
SELECT drinker
FROM likes l1
WHERE beer = 'Bud'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM likes l2 WHERE l2.drinker=l1.drinker and l2.beer <> "Bud");
```

What it pretty much does is that it selects those drinkers that like Bud and tgen checks if those like anything else. `not exists` returns true if no records match the condition in the subquery.

Comment: It does allegedly generate the best `explain` plan

Comment: @shadow what does `SELECT 1` do? I've never come across this

Comment: I provided the link to the documentation. It is explained there.

Answer (score 1):

For your drinkers that only like Bud:

```
SELECT a.DRINKER
  FROM (SELECT DRINKER
          FROM LIKES
          WHERE BEER = 'BUD') a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DRINKER, COUNT(*)
                FROM LIKES
                GROUP BY DRINKER
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) b
    ON b.DRINKER = a.DRINKER
```

The first sub-query (a) is your query which pulls back everyone who likes Bud. The second subquery (b) returns all drinkers who only like one thing. Joining them together gets you drinkers who only like Bud.

Best of luck.

Comment: what does the `COUNT(*)` do? My logic was to find the ones who like bud and having COUNT(beer) = 1 but couldn't figure out how to conjoin it. Also  I don't believe I have been taught the `INNER JOIN` or `ON` commands yet, is there a different way to do this?

Comment: There is no need to have nested subqueries. Have the count(*) subquery but then join it back to the likes table and use the where condition in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution accesses the table only once, if both the min and the max are the same there's only one value:

```
SELECT drinker
FROM likes
GROUP BY drinker
HAVING MIN(beer) = 'Bud'
   AND MAX(beer) = 'Bud';
```

Comment: I like this solution its creative. So how do the lines `Having MIN(beer) = 'Bud' AND MAX(beer) = 'Bud';` work? I am not quite understanding the min(beer) = bud or max(beer) = bud either. Although it does provide me the correct data

Comment: @bkennedy: As HAVING is evaluated after aggregation there can't be any other value than `'Bud'`. You might add the min/max to the Select list and run the query without Having to see the base data.