# Get grouped ID with common values

Tags: mysql

It's possible to get all id_products with common id_feature_values?

```
id_feature | id_product | id_feature_value
---------- | ---------- | -----------------
17         | 4900       | 388
18         | 4900       | 398
20         | 4901       | 400
21         | 4901       | 401
17         | 4902       | 388
17         | 4902       | 398
```

For example, I want id_products with id_feature_value 388 and 398, so the result I need is 4900 and 4902.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nonmonotone SQL queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692379/nonmonotone-sql-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_product FROM <tablename> WHERE id_feature_value IN (398, 388) GROUP BY id_product HAVING COUNT(id_feature_value)=2
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d537e/3

Comment: Your query is right but you didn't apply condition to get only id_products with id_feature_value 388 and 398. I don't know how to apply that condition to you query:

WHERE id_feature_value = 388 AND id_feature_value = 398

Comment: Hmm, more close to solution but you used id_feature_value OR id_feature_value. That is not exactly I'm looking for.
I need id_feature_value AND id_feature_value, but id_product with these values are in differents rows.

Comment: I edited once again! This will definitely work. I tried it out! :)

Comment: Your query used IN and this sentence is not exclusive. Test kbball query and look your result. Is different :(

Comment: @DavidS.P. I have been using your table columns in a reversed way (id_product for id_feature_value and vice versa). Hence the confusion. Now, if you look at it (Edited again), the result would be the exact same.

Comment: Do I need HAVING here? I'm confused! @Shadow

Comment: Look this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d537e/1 your query got id_product 4903 too and this one only have id_feature_value 398 but not 388.

Comment: Yes, you do. If you took a look at the duplicate topic I linked, you will find the correct version of your answer. This one is not correct at the moment.

Comment: Aaah! Gotcha! What a boo boo mistake! :D Sorry about that!

Comment: @Shadow I think it is correct now isnt it? Please take a look :)